# Como retirar o som do BIP do Windows no c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows

espero que vocês estejam bem.
Desenvolvi um aplicativo em C# no Visual Studio, mas ao apertar a tecla 'TAB' pra mudar de textBox1 para textBox2, ele faz o som do Windows (que na verdade é a tecla ENTER que mudei no script).
Como faz pra tirar esse som?
Tentei o código abaixo mas não deu certo...

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

Obrigado!

Comment: como alterou pra tecla Enter ?

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que prevenir que o evento `KeyPressed` seja gerado, que é o tal beep. Para isso, tem que indicar que o evento foi finalizado com sucesso:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
    {
        textBox2.Select();
        textBox2.Focus();
        e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas nao funcionou. Alias sua dica funcionou, mas achei o problema...era um bloco que tinha colocado para acionar a tecla Tab no lugar de Enter. Tive que comentar esse bloco todo prá tirar o beep chato....valeu!